# Microsoft Power BI Designer data model to Excel or PowerPivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, powerbi

Is there a way to get a Microsoft Power BI Designer data model into Excel to work with in Powerpivot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, Power BI Designer files are not compatible with Excel.

Please see the following link:http://blogs.technet.com/b/powerbisupport/archive/2014/12/19/power-bi-designer-preview.aspx

> We also cannot cross between Excel and the Power BI Designer. For
>   example, if we have a Data Model in Excel, I can't use that and create
>   reports within the Power BI Designer. Also, if I have a Data Model in
>   Power BI Designer, I can point Excel to use that. You have to pick one
>   or the other.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. Suggest that you post a suggestion at support.PowerBI.com.

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is not possible, but they are exploring a few options. You can vote there, if you think that is your need. These do not talk about using the data from PowerBI Designer files to Excel, but at least you can export/import charts.

https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6708045-power-point-integration

https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi/suggestions/6708045-power-point-integration

As pointed out earlier by @PowerDAX you need to pick one or the other. Besides this, all data sources that you have for Power BI Designer are also available for Excel.